# Gedit and Filezilla Input Problem

Tags: gtk, gedit, 14.10, filezilla

I upgraded 14.04 to 14.10. I installed my apps(lamp, nodejs, filezilla, phpstorm, git etc.). I have some input problems in some apps.

In Filezilla,

- I can't use tab and delete keys
- Some UI problems, in filezilla tabs

In Gedit,

- After 2-3 minute I can't write anymore. (Old keys writing sometimes) (No keyboard problem) (I think GTK or RAM problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems a lot of issues have been raised regarding input problems lately: [ibus issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1007423)

Try going to

1. Input Method > OK > YES: Change from ibus to none or xim.
2. Language Support > Keyboard input method system: none

This is a workaround until a definitive fix is released.

Cheers

Comment: I changed ibus to none from Input Method, Also I set Keyboard input method system to none.  But problem still not fixed.

But, Thank you for answer Christian :)

Comment: It appears that the answer was accepted prior to testing. Comment came in 1/2 hour later than acceptance.

Comment: It seems this has not solved the problem. As a workaround everytime that happens I restart Ibus: `ibus restart`

Comment: i have simmilar problem, but it comes only when pressing control+c or v or any key kombination, but only in filzella and gedit, netbeans firefox chrome  mousepad is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the [ibus-gtk](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ibus-gtk) [image: Install ibus-gtk] package, by clicking that link or running with `sudo apt-get install ibus-gtk` and restart you computer. That fixed this issue for me.

Comment: This solved the problem of a non-functioning backspace / delete button  in FileZilla for me on ubuntu 14.10. Thank you.

Comment: Also solved my problems with FileZilla on Ubuntu 14.10.