# Can't jump between input fields in Filezilla 3.9.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: 14.10, filezilla

I set up a clean Ubuntu 14.10 and am wondering why I can't use the tabulator key on the keyboard to jump between input fields for server, user, ...

Answer (score 0):

Follow the answer posted here -

[Gedit and Filezilla Input Problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/545909/gedit-and-filezilla-input-problem)

I followed the same process, but selected 'xim' and there was no need to change language support for me. I am using Xubuntu 14.10. After that I restarted the machine and tab keys are working fine now.

Comment: Thanks! But it does not seem to change anything...